# AjaxControlToolkit : TabContainer

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit, tabcontainer

Looking for developers who have experienced this problem and have implemented a working solution...

I have been using the TabContainer control successfully in my VB.Net 3.5 web app for years. It has worked in the web app that I am experiencing a problem with for at least 2 years both on my local machine and the live web server.

However, I have moved the site to a different server and now the TabContainer controls are not working. I am thinking that I need to change a server setting or a file permission? I don't believe that I need to change my code (script tag, web.config, etc).

Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: UPDATE -- I meant to say that the control is not displaying.

Comment: user1422570: Try editing your post to reflect your update instead of adding that as a comment